# Kotlin casting between classes fails

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm learning to code in Android with Kotlin, and have issues when casting between classes.

So I had these classes defined:

```
abstract class ListFragment : Fragment()
class NewListFragment : ListFragment()
```

and when I tried to use it when implementing a function that returns a Fragment, it throws ClassCastException. There was IDE warning about the failing cast too

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return when(position){
        0 -> NewListFragment() as Fragment
```

I don't know where I got wrong

Comment: Can you please include the exception?

Comment: You dont need to cast `as Fragment` it will directly take like this
`return when(position){
        0 -> NewListFragment()`

Comment: @s1m0nw1 The error message is just plain `java.lang.ClassCastException: deng.jitian.raeder.NewListFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. No really valuable things to be found after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the *same* `Fragment` class?

- [`android.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) (deprecated as of Android P)
- [`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

You seem to be casting to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, judging from the exception message. Are your imports in that file incorrect?

The warning in IntelliJ about an impossible cast only appears when it is truly impossible to cast to that specific type (that is, when their type hierarchies are completely different), which is why I think that this is likely the problem.

Additionally, you don't *need* to cast to a supertype. Such a conversion is already inferred, so you can remove the cast.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That's exactly the problem. Shamefully I considered the exception message unhelpful.